# Why CacheStorage.open promise never responds?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, promise, cachestorage

We've started using CacheStorage API. Generally it works fine, but sometimes browser gets into a situation where CacheStorage promises never respond (i.e. they neither resolve nor reject).

Once I get into the situation I can reproduce it 100% on a first call like:

```
let promise = caches.open("TestDB");
console.log("open - started");

promise
.then(cc => console.log("open - complete"))
.catch(ex => console.log("open - failed", ex));

console.log("open - waiting");
```

In the sample code it will print:

```
open - started 
open - waiting
```

but **never** the other two logs.

*Any ideas why would this happen? and how to address the issue?*

If I open a private tab, then it works fine. Clearing the cache from UI solves the problem too.

This has been reproduced on Chrome and Safari.

---

We've seen other situations where `open` call succeeds, but then `match` fails (i.e. doesn't resolve) randomly, i.e. it seems to depend on the number of requests to the cache, as adding `console.log` seems to make the problem less frequent.

Comment: Sounds like buggy behaviour. Maybe you could pass all cache requests through some kind of rate limiter. I'm pretty certain there's at least one good rate limiter answer somewhere on SO - possibly by Esailija?

Comment: We've made the same conclusion - must be a browser bug. Limiter could help in some situations, but generally, the problem would remain, because once you get into that situation it starts failing very early very easily without a big load.

Comment: Paulius, good luck with it.